# type-graphql: How to know which fields are returned by Resolver

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql

I am writing a backend application that uses type-graphql. The GraphQL schema includes a `Folder` type that looks like this:

```
type Folder {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  rules: [Rule!]!
  parent: Group
}
```

`Rule` and `Group` are other types.

My Resolver defines a Query called `folders` that returns all Folders:

```
import {Query, Resolver} from 'type-graphql'

@Resolver(() => Folder)
export default class FolderResolver {

  @Query(() => [Folder])
  folders(): Promise<Folder[]> {
    // query db and return results
  }
}
```

To query the folders, their rules, and their parent group from the database, I have to join the database tables and return the joined result, which works without problems. However: If the `rules` field and / or the `parent` field was not requested in the GraphQL query, I could omit the joins and make the database query much more efficient. So the fields that were requested in the GraphQL query have a definite effect on the logic that I need to execute, but I don't see a way of finding out which fields were requested inside the `folders` function.

When a Query in a type-graphql Resolver is executed, is there a way to determine which fields were requested in the GraphQL query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at [Field Resolver](https://typegraphql.com/docs/0.17.0/resolvers.html#field-resolvers). The annotation is specifically made for such purpose

```ts
import {Query, Resolver, FieldResolver} from 'type-graphql'

@Resolver(() => Folder)
export default class FolderResolver {

  @FieldResolver()
  rules(@Root() folder: Folder) {
    // ...
  }


  @FieldResolver()
  parent(@Root() folder: Folder) {
    // ...
  }

  @Query(() => [Folder])
  folders(): Promise<Folder[]> {
    // query db and return results
  }
}
```

Now, when a user requests a query without `rules` or `parent` as a part of their attributes, they won't be called, if they do either or both will be called. Your logic to fetch data for them resides in their own field resolvers.

---

Updated as per comment:

If you have to get fields queries by the clients, you may use a library like [graphql-fields](https://github.com/robrichard/graphql-fields). This helps you to extracts fields from the `info` parameter of the resolver function. Something like this: (as mentioned in the docs)

```ts
  import graphqlFields from 'graphql-fields';

  @Query(() => [Folder])
  folders(@Info() info: GraphQLResolveInfo): Promise<Folder[]> {
    // get fields
    const topLevelFields = Object.keys(graphqlFields(info));
    // query db and return results
  }
```

Now you can run your query based on the requested fields.

Comment: I don't think the Field Resolver helps here unfortunately.

If neither `parent` nor `rules` is requested, I want `folders` to execute a database query that queries only the folder table. If `parent` and / or `rules` is requested, I want `folders` to execute a database query that queries the folder table and joins on the parent and / or rule table (which I currently do no matter what fields are requested from the GraphQL query). In either case, I want to perform a single database query. I'm hoping that I can execute that query inside `folders` and shape it based on the requested fields.

Comment: @MatthiasFischer I have updayed the answer as per your comment. Have a look.

Comment: Awesome! The `@Info` decorator is exactly what I was missing. The graphqlFields library seems really useful, too, I will check it out. Thanks a lot!